# How to use multiple virtual monitors if host has a single monitor?

Tags: virtual-machine, multiple-monitors

My host has a single physical monitor but I need to reproduce a bug in an application that requires two monitors, each having a different scaling factor.

VMWare provides [documentation](http://pubs.vmware.com/ws6_ace2/ws/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=ws&file=ws_running_display_multiple_monitors.html) for cycling through multiple virtual machines but it requires the host to have multiple physical monitors.

How can one cycle through multiple virtual monitors with a single physical host monitor?

**UPDATE**: The guest is Windows 10. The host is either Windows or MacOS.

Comment: What OS on the host and VMs?

Comment: This search brings up several QAs you should probably read: https://superuser.com/search?q=virtual+monitors+in+vmware And here are a few of the most relevant-appearing from the top of that search: https://superuser.com/questions/680841/possible-to-have-multiple-virtual-monitors-for-a-vmware-guest-in-windowed-mode https://superuser.com/questions/1176221/multiple-virtual-monitors-in-linux-guest-with-vmware-workstation-12

Comment: @music2myear Question updated. https://superuser.com/q/1176221/57662 looks promising but it is a Windows 7 guest and does not explain how he got it working. https://superuser.com/a/964511/57662 is Windows 7 specific and doesn't seem to work on Windows 10.

Comment: @Gili It being a Windows 7 guest doesn’t chnage how it’s accomplished

Comment: @Ramhound It might make a difference. When I go into "Display Properties" I don't have an interface for configuring multiple monitors. When I go into "Device Manager" I only see a single monitor. I assume that is part of the problem. This is what I see running Windows 10 as a guest in windowed mode.

Comment: @Gili didn't my answer work for you ?

Answer (score 4):

With some effort I've managed to configure multiple virtual monitors using VMWare Workstation for a Windows 10 guest.

**Host:**

- Windows 7 Pro x64
- VMWare Workstation Pro 12.5.9 build-7535481

**Guest:**

- Windows 10 Pro 1709 x64 with all updates and current VMware Tools installed

**VMWare Virtual Machine Display Settings:**

- 3D graphics → checked *Accelerate 3D graphics*
- Monitors → selected *Specify monitor settings*

  - Number of monitors: 4
  - Maximum resolution of any one monitor: 1920x1080
- Graphics memory: 256M
- Display scaling → unchecked *Automatically adjust user interface size ...*

**Preparations**

- Start the Windows 10 guest
- Don't use Full Screen
- From VMWare Workstation's menu select *View* → *Autosize* → *Center Guest*

**Configuration inside the Windows 10 guest machine:**

Right-click on the Desktop, select *Display settings* and set the resolution to 800x600 (simply
 to better see the additional monitors created in the following steps).

Now you will notice that nothing happens if you click the *Detect* button under *Multiple Displays*.

Note: In previous Windows versions you were offered an option *"try to connect anyway on: VGA"* if the display was not detected.
This might be a bug (or feature) introduced with Windows 10 Version 1703. There is a [Microsoft Technet Question](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f1342ab1-acb3-49ea-aed4-2acd492aca53/windows-10-2nd-display-broken-after-update-to-version-1703-creators-update-build-15063138?forum=win10itprogeneral) providing more information.

However, you can still force this by following the next steps:

- Run the following command: `displayswitch.exe`
- Alternatively simply use the Windows + P hotkey (inside the Guest !)

This will bring up the *Project* settings plane. Choose *Extend*:

[image: Windows 10 Project Settings]

Et voilà, now you have two monitors:

[image: Windows 10 VMWare guest with two virtual monitors]

And of course you now also see the usual multiple display options in the Display Settings.

In order to add the third monitor, press *Detect*. This will create a new box labeled *Display not detected*. You have to click on that box so that it gets highlighted in blue:

[image: Windows 10 VMWare guest detect additional virtual monitor]

Now scroll down to *Multiple Displays* section and change the selection in the drop-down box from *No display detected* to the **bottom-most** entry *Try to connect anyway on: VGA*:

[image: Windows 10 VMWare guest connect to undetected virtual monitor]

Repeat this process for additional monitors.

You can also align the monitors to your liking:

[image: Windows 10 VMWare guest with 4 virtual monitors]

Comment: This solution does not apply to VMware Fusion (MacOS Host). There is no option to select the number of monitors.

Comment: This solution does not work for me for the following reason: (1) The "Select and rearrange display" dialog shows 4 monitors, but only 3 are rendered inside the guest. (2) All but the first monitor do not respond to right-mouse mouse clicks. Windows cannot be dragged from one virtual monitor to another. In short, we're getting close to a solution but this functionality seems to be broken in its current state. This was tested using a Windows 10.0.17134.254 host and a Windows 10.0.16299.125 guest.

Comment: @Gili I've added an additional screenshot showing 4 virtual monitors. No issues with right-clicks. I guess you're doing something wrong. Make sure you have selected View → Autosize → Center Guest. However, I've shown the basic concept and given a valid answer to your question. If you experience bugs you might add a new question or try to get support from VMWare. Cheers.